# How to create report using arcpy in arcgis 10.2 (result the same as using view -> Reports -> Create Report)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, reports, create

[image]

I need to create reports in arcgis 10.2. because I am not intent to request user to go through all the steps for generating reports, so I want to create an add-in tool to do this. The result is the same as the picture, Can it be realized?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The Report Writer can only be used interactively to author reports.

However, once you have authored your Report Layout Format (*.rlf) file you can use it with the **[ExportReport (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000062000000)** function to export data from tables or feature classes into the report layout that you have pre-authored.

This functionality could be placed behind a Python AddIn tool.

Answer (score 2):

An open-source Python option is the [ReportLab toolkit](http://www.reportlab.com/opensource/). Esri even uses it for some of their projects. The [documentation](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) is pretty good, and there are [tons](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/) of [examples](http://www.protocolostomy.com/2008/10/22/generating-reports-with-charts-using-python-reportlab/) on [getting started](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1564/pdf-with-reportlab-ii) out on the web ([below from Mouse V. Python](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/))

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf")
c.drawString(100,750,"Welcome to Reportlab!")
c.save()
```

In your case, you'd want to loop through a cursor of your records and add them into a table in your pdf canvas.

Comment: Hi Chad, I just had a look at the ReportLab, does it only support the pdf format?

Comment: I've used ReportLab quite a bit and like it but I think the learning curve is much steeper than for the in-built Report Writer.  @littleleaf http://www.reportlab.com/software/documentation/